# The existence of solutions of a system of indeterminate equations

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $m$ be a positive integer satisfying $\dfrac{m(m+1)}{4}\in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that there exists a positive integer $t$ and $t$ positive integers $m_1,m_2,\cdots,m_t$ such that $$\begin{cases} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{t}m_k=m\\ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{t}\dfrac{m_k(m_k+1)}{2}=\dfrac{m(m+1)}{4} \end{cases}.$$
P.S. This question comes from Problem F in The 2022 ICPC Asia Shenyang Regional Contest (https://codeforces.com/gym/104160/problem/F). One of the key steps in this problem is to find a set of solutions to the above indeterminate equations. And I noticed that $\dfrac{m(m+1)}{4}$ cannot be arbitrarily replaced by other positive integers, which may make the proposition no longer true.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "cannot be replaced bu other positive integers"? It can surely be replaced, say, with $m$ yielding a solution $t=m$ and $m_k=1$ for all $k$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Sorry, what I originally meant to express is that it cannot be **arbitrarily** replaced by other positive integers.

Comment: To be exact $\frac{m(m+1)}4$ is not just an integer but a function of parameter $m$. It **can** be replaced with other functions of $m$, and so your comment is misleading at best.

Comment: I found that this [Sage code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdj0sKwjAQhtct9A4hq0na2gdFpBAh5xAXhaZa2iQ1CboQ7-5EwYWzmef_zcyoJuLtelegWZ-liRSag84bVlUdppubTYCJPvWrJ7RQZhSUMmwMxovTGYPHdV4Vkcc6qpMgoMmn1VoH_uYCHDjIUjPkMSS2cQSVu2HbEAUhkhJdihC9RM8hfHbHycF7hQgpRM1-p6AakyydrCMLmQ1xg7koaIp2H-8naN93Or6UDfursDeQNjwm&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) seems to always find a set of solutions for small $m$. The general idea of this algorithm is to select $m_k$ as large as possible in each iteration. Can anyone prove the correctness of this algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: What is your question? Note that MO is a question-and-answer site.

Comment: @GHfromMO: As I understand it, the question is to prove that the given system of equations has a solution $(m_1,\dots,m_t)$ for any positive integer $m$ such that $\frac{m(m+1)}4\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev That's not a question, but a request/order to prove something.

Comment: @GHfromMO: It's just a matter of formulation. Here is a question - "does this system has a solution for every $m$?"

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I see. So is the answer affirmative? Probably yes, but your answers do not make that very clear. (Note that the original formulation of the problem assumes that the answer is "yes", in which case the question you suggest is not a question, really.)

Comment: @GHfromMO: Yes, see my answer where I prove that the greedy algorithm always produces a solution.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev OK. It might be helpful to start your solution by claiming that a solution to the OP's equations always exists.

Comment: @GHfromMO: Good point! I've updated the answer to make clear its contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments OP proposed a greedy algorithm to represent a given positive integer $A$ as the sum of triangular numbers whose indices sum to $m$, and applied it to $A = \frac{m(m+1)}4$. I will prove that it indeed always produces a solution, and thus the given system is soluble for any positive integer $m$ with $\frac{m(m+1)}4\in\mathbb Z$.

---

Essentially, the algorithm goes from a pair $(m,A)$ with $m\leq A$ to the pair $(m-t,A-\tfrac{t(t+1)}2)$ for the largest integer $t$ such that $m-t \leq A-\tfrac{t(t+1)}2$, or equivalently
$$(\star)\qquad \frac{t(t-1)}2\leq A-m < \frac{t(t+1)}2.$$ The value for $t$ can be given explicitly as
$t = \left\lfloor\tfrac{1 + \sqrt{8(A-m)+1}}2\right\rfloor.$
Notice that $t\geq 1$, and furthermore $t\geq 2$ as soon as $m<A$.

The algorithm converges and produces a solution when/if it reaches the pair $(0,0)$. Let's start with the following claim.

**Claim.** The greedy algorithm converges for any given pair of integers $(m,A)$ satisfying $0\leq m\leq A \leq \frac{(m-1)^2}4$.

**Proof.** Proof is done by induction on $m$. In the base cases $m< 43$ the claim is verified computationally. Let's prove the claim for $m\geq 43$, assuming that it's proved for all smaller values of $m$.

The algorithm from the given pair $(m,A)$ goes to the pair $(m',A')$ where $m':=m-t$ and $A':=A-\frac{t(t+1)}2$ with $t\geq 1$ defined by the formula above. Clearly, $m'<m$. Hence, for the induction assumption to work it remains to verify that
$0\leq m'\leq A'\leq \frac{(m'-1)^2}4$.

It can be seen that inequality $0\leq m'$ (ie. $t\leq m$) follows from the inequality $A \leq \frac{(m-1)^2}4$ coupled with $(\star)$.
The inequality $m'\leq A'$ follows from the definition of $t$.

Finally, the inequality $A' \leq \frac{(m'-1)^2}4$, given that $(\star)$ implies $A'<m$, would follow from $m \leq \frac{(m-t-1)^2}4$, for which we need $t \leq m-1-2\sqrt{m}$. Since $A\leq \frac{(m-1)^2}4$, from the explicit formula for $t$, we have
$$t\leq \frac{1 + \sqrt{2(m^2-6m+1)+1}}2<\frac{1+\sqrt{2}(m-3)}2\leq m-1-2\sqrt{m},$$
where the last inequality holds since $m\geq 43$. QED

---

While Claim is not directly applicable to $A = \frac{m(m+1)}4$, we show that for $m\geq 50$ after one iteration the pair $(m',A'):=(m-t,A-\frac{t(t+1)}2)$ does satisfy the condition of Claim. Similarly to the above, it's enough to show that $t \leq m-1-2\sqrt{m}$. Here the explicit formula for $t$ implies
$$t\leq \frac{1 + \sqrt{2(m^2-3m)+1}}2<\frac{1+\sqrt{2}(m-1.5)}2\leq m-1-2\sqrt{m},$$
where the last inequality holds for $m\geq 50$. Hence, our Claim implies that the algorithm converges on the input $(m,\frac{m(m+1)}4)$ for all $m\geq 50$. For $m<50$, the algorithm convergence on the input $(m,\frac{m(m+1)}4)$ is verified computationally.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that in many cases the following construction will do the job. By [Fermat polygonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_polygonal_number_theorem), we have representation of $\frac{m(m-3)}4$ as the sum of 3 triangular numbers:
$$ \frac{m(m-3)}4 = \frac{m_1(m_1-1)}2 + \frac{m_2(m_2-1)}2 + \frac{m_3(m_3-1)}2$$
and if additionally we can have $m_1+m_2+m_3\leq m$, we set $t:=m-(m_1+m_2+m_3)+3$ and $m_k:=1$ for $k\in\{4,5,\dots,t\}$ to get a solution.

Here is an [online Sage code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNj9EKgkAURN8F_2Fegrtq6GpPgX1CPyAiQrshdXdrV8P-PheNmsfhzpy5F6XBb2_vL0UsjnGERR41GppTKfK8hLYOMwYDP3FndXfr_HPqnfJUZWXCCfG-Emkl2jU86HBIXuAE3gqDnBonZ3C2Rq3mZnikaGQbataciKM4ClAOUNebqyKZyUJ-5y2EQF3mYYcD6hrFH-fhBjMSZ7-vxAfpRzw8&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) that implements this approach. Relying on just one (somewhat arbitrary) representation produced by `sum_of_k_squares(3,x)` it solves the problem for all 50 suitable values of $m$ below $100$, except $m=60$. Moreover, I was not able to find any other exceptional integers in the range $m\leq 10^5$, and so it may be the only exception to the above approach overall. Still, the problem for $m=60$ can be solved similarly via considering representations as the sum of 4 triangular numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I found that this [Sage code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdj0sKwjAQhtct9A4hq0na2gdFpBAh5xAXhaZa2iQ1CboQ7-5EwYWzmef_zcyoJuLtelegWZ-liRSag84bVlUdppubTYCJPvWrJ7RQZhSUMmwMxovTGYPHdV4Vkcc6qpMgoMmn1VoH_uYCHDjIUjPkMSS2cQSVu2HbEAUhkhJdihC9RM8hfHbHycF7hQgpRM1-p6AakyydrCMLmQ1xg7koaIp2H-8naN93Or6UDfursDeQNjwm&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) seems to always find a set of solutions for small $m$. The general idea of this algorithm is to select $m_k$ as large as possible in each iteration. Can anyone prove the correctness of this algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: Your comment is irrelevant to my answer. You describe a greedy algorithm.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I just said that I found another possible way to construct the solution.